# forgiving solr indexing

Tags: solr

It is possible for solr to index documents in a more forgivable way?

Currently I always get a SolrException if I try to index data witch doesn't fit the schema for one hundred percent. It would be better if solr could index the document anyway and prints an exception for the fields which are incorrect.

Comment: IMHO you should try to fix your indexing process instead...

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off with a schema-less search, like http://www.elasticsearch.org/

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: You are right about that, but I have a large and sometimes a litte inconsistent data basis. So i cannot garuantee that wrong data is passed through solr. It would be much easier if solr can handle it for me.

Comment: @Paul Dixon: Thanks for the idea, but I cannot do that due political reasons

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server solr is running on and can see the logs solr gives this information. There is a setting you can put in the schema that captures all of a certain type  that can be found in the example within the download

catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema

```
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I don't see how this solves my problem. A catchall field doesn't take over in case of an error. In my database I have a field which should be occur only once, but in some inconsistent data sets its defined twice. So I wan't solr to ignore just the second value or ignore the whole field and index the document anyway. I can easily set the field as multiple, but I don't like that.

Comment: Your best bet would be to look at the logs as this would give you the information you require. The logs will tell you what field is throwing an error and why i.e datatype mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little on @Si Philp's answer. If you look at the example [schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) that comes with the Solr distribution, you will see the following entries:

```
<!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing 
    field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error. 
    alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want 
    unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default --> 
<!--dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" /-->

<!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed,
     any data added to them will be ignored outright.  --> 
<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true"
  class="solr.StrField" />
```

This will create a dynamic definition in your schema for any fields that are not already defined, they will be ignored. It will not however, give you any indicator of the fields/values that are being ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have this already in my schema.xml, but this doesn't solve any multiValued or wrong field type (string -> integer) kind of issues.

Comment: I do not know of anything within Solr that can handle those types of errors for you. Solr is not a data validation tool, it assumes you are handling those types of issues prior to loading your data. You will need to account for those types of things on your own before submitting data to Solr to be indexed.